# How to get number of buttons in an Windows Phone application bar

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, application-bar

I have an application bar in my Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app. It contains one `ApplicationBarButton` and when the user scrolls to a certain point in the `LongListSelector` another button is added to the `ApplicationBar` like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
     ApplicationBarIconButton scrollToToday = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
     scrollToToday.Text = "idag";
     scrollToToday.IconUri = new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/today_dark.png", UriKind.Relative);
     parent.ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(scrollToToday);
}
```

When the user then scrolls back to the original point start point I remove it with:

```
parent.ApplicationBar.Buttons.RemoveAt(1);
```

But the app crashes when it reaches that code line when the app is started since the app starts in the original starting point and then there is no second button to remove. I think it has to do with that I first must check that if the `ApplicationBar` contains more than one button it is okay to remove the button at index 1. But how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need a `for` loop to add the button, since you're adding only one:

```
 ApplicationBarIconButton scrollToToday = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
 scrollToToday.Text = "idag";
 scrollToToday.IconUri = new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/today_dark.png", UriKind.Relative);
 parent.ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(scrollToToday);
```

Then, if I understand correctly, you want to remove the last button if there's more than one. If so, you can use this code:

```
var count = parent.ApplicationBar.Buttons.Count;

if (count >= 2)
{
    parent.ApplicationBar.Buttons.RemoveAt(count - 1);
}
```

(storing `count` in a temporary variable isn't mandatory, I just did this to increase readability)

Answer (score 0):

Check the number of buttons first, you need Linq for that:

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 if(parent.ApplicationBar.Buttons.Count() > 1)
      parent.ApplicationBar.Buttons.RemoveAt(1);
```

Comment: 'System.Collections.IList' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.IList' could be found @KooKiz answer is the correct one for me

Comment: as I stated, you need Linq, add this to the top of your file `using System.Linq;`